# Java Print API renders on paper skewed graphics

Tags: java, printing, jvm, graphics2d

There are 3 elements painted on imageable area in the same way. But Java Print Service draws them differently depends on whether some conditions are repected.

2 conditions are respected when paint bug occurs:

1. Page orientation is set to LANDSCAPE
2. Alpha value in Color to fill any area is less than 255

Code snippet to reproduce it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class Printing implements Printable {
    private static Paper paper;
    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (Thread.interrupted())
        {
            throw new PrinterException("Current thread interrupted.");
        }

        Stroke oldstroke = ((Graphics2D)graphics).getStroke();
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(15, 0);
        graphics.drawLine(0,0,0,300); //LEFT margin line
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(-15, 0);

        ((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(0, -15);
        graphics.drawLine(0,(int)paper.getImageableWidth(),300,(int)paper.getImageableWidth());//BOTTOM margin line
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(0, 15);
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).setStroke(oldstroke);

        ((Graphics2D)graphics).setPaint(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,100));
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).fill(new Rectangle(0,0,200,200));


        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Printing printer = new Printing();
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
        paper = pageFormat.getPaper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0,0,paper.getWidth(),paper.getHeight());
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(printer, pageFormat,1);
        printJob.setPageable(book);
        try {
            printJob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When application runs without

```
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).setPaint(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0,100));
        ((Graphics2D)graphics).fill(new Rectangle(0,0,200,200));
```

then left and bottom lines are visible on the paper, otherwise the only rectangle is visible.

It seems that Java Print Service replaces origin point.
Is it either the JVM trouble or I mistaked somewhere?

Comment: It's tracked as [JDK-8307246](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8307246): _Printing: banded raster path doesn't account for device offset values_.